# Node - Express 4 csrf

Tags: node.js, security, express, connect, csrf

With the dawn of [Express 4](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) connect is no longer a dependancy. I can't find on the express site any new implementation of csrf.

the old way was `app.use(express.csrf());` and then add in a middleware function to expose it in the view.

My question is: Am I now forced to include connect as a dependency, or is there something baked into express now that allows for csrf that I am missing?

Or can I just include the [source](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html) of csrf into my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install and require [csurf](https://github.com/expressjs/csurf) for Express 4.